# multiple jquery sliders load saved value

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using multiple Jquery sliders on a page, when the page loads I want to load a previously stored value, so one slider might default to 25%, another to 50% etc,.

I found a similar question and solution here:

[Jquery UI slider handle on last saved value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024567/jquery-ui-slider-handle-on-last-saved-value)

This works ok for one slider, but not for several!

For example my slider code:

```
<div class="sliderVal" id="slider1"></div>
<div class="partialOutput" id="partial1" data-parlossval="50">50%</div>
```

Then my jquery:

```
$( ".sliderVal" ).slider({
    value: parseInt(".partialOutput").data("parlossval")),
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
```

But this is not unique to any slider, I tried using the following "$(this)" object but when I run it the slider bar disappears:

```
$( ".sliderVal" ).slider({
        value: parseInt($(this).(".partialOutput").data("parlossval")),
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: in your jquery youre selecting the class which will get all of hte sliders. Try `$("#slider1").slider({....` This will only select the slider with the `id` of slider1

Comment: @kierchon I'm not able to call the id of the slider, because there are multiple sliders but only a single slider declaration which handles the setup for each slider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the id instead of the class in your jQuery selector. This will get specific HTML elements instead of every element with that class.

Try

```
$( "#slider1" ).slider({
    value: parseInt("#partial1").data("parlossval")),
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
});
```

Then for mutliple sliders just create a slider for each slider div.

```
$( "#slider2" ).slider({
    value: parseInt("#partial2").data("parlossval")),
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [create event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create) to set the values:

```
$(".sliderVal").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).slider('value',$(this).next().data('parlossval'));
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4PAQU/)**